# Mapstruct null strategy default crea un constructor bigdecimal sin parametros

Tags: java, spring

Estoy tratando de hacer un mapeo con MapStruct utilizando el null strategy por defecto, y al crear la implementación este está creando un constructor de BigDecimal sin parametros, lo cual no existe y por tanto da fallo de compilacion.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        uses = { EnumMappings.class, BooleanYNMapper.class,
            OffsetDateTimeToString.class }, 
        nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT
)
public interface ServicioEmitirSolicitudESBEntradaMapper {

    @Mappings(value = {
        ...
        @Mapping(target = "datosEntradaAmazonSDO.codComerTar",
             source = "body.firstReceiptRedsysOperation.merchantCode")
             ...
        }
    )
    EmitirSolicitudEntradaAmazonSDO map(Headers headers,
            InPostIndividualInsuranceApplicationIdPolicy body,
            String insuranceApplicationId);
```

Y esto crea un codigo :

```
 if ( redsysOperation.getMerchantCode() != null ) {
        mappingTarget.setCodComerTar( new BigDecimal( redsysOperation.getMerchantCode() ) );
    }
    else {
        mappingTarget.setCodComerTar( new BigDecimal() );
    }
```

Y esta ultima linea es la que no es correcta.

¿Alguien sabe como corregir esto?

Comment: Sin ver las dos clases involucradas es complicado dar una solución. Pero mapstruct permit definir métodos auxiliares para hacer las transformaciones

Comment: Creo que las clases aquí no importan, el caso es que mapstruts cree que el valor por defecto de bigdecimal es un constructor vacio, y este no existe. Se que existen otras opciones para hacer el cambio "a mano" pero quería saber como configurar esto para evitar que utilice un constructor vacio